# View post photo from friends using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, post

I want to make my app to become less boring, one way to do it is by showing post photos from friends on the home tab. I manage to do some of it by using graph api.

I am using this graph to view my friend activities

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&access_token=erqaer
```

result:

```
 "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/157108_525475649_53898163_q.jpg",
 "link": "http://www.facebook.com/sample",
 "type": "link",
```

I get to get this photo by getting the picture data, but on post photos I can't.

**Post Photos**

using the same graph above,

result:

```
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=12234444",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/23434352/posts/12143343434"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/121214334/posts/34343434344"
        }
     ],
     "type": "photo",
     "object_id": "357309684280810",
```

I only get this data. There's no picture data that I can get to view post photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=504135887) to experiment with Facebook's API.  When you query :
`htttps://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID` you should get back all the information from that post.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying that, but still no luck.